# How to remove yellow selection highlight?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdfkit

I'm selection text programmatically in PDFKit and after tap, for 2 seconds selected word is highlighted in yellow, then disappears.

```
let wordSelection = page?.selectionForWord(at: info.point)
pdfView.setCurrentSelection(wordSelection, animate: true)
```

Would be perfect for me to remove this highlight or to replace it with .clear color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that if I'm setting `animate` property to `false` it disappears.

```
pdfView.setCurrentSelection(wordSelection, animate: false)
```